# Have Rails 'image_tag' to browse image outside the /public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I am trying to use Paperclip with Heroku. And yes, according to [Heroku's Application Constraints](http://docs.heroku.com/constraints). I'll be able to store the uploaded files into /tmp or /.log folder only, which is totally located outside the /public folder.

**If we are not going to talk about Amazon S3**, how can I access the image in the /tmp directory with **image_tag** tag.

This is my model of the photo, that using Paperclip

```
class ObbProductphoto < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :product

has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:high => '1024x768', :medium => '640x480', :thumb => '100x100'},
:path => "tmp/:id.:extension",
:url => "tmp/:id.:extension"
end
```

And this is what I got in the browser:

```
<img src="/images/tmp/24.JPG?1294433924" alt="24" />
```

It still using the /images folder,

I tried to hack any **/..** or **../**, couldn't get the solution.

*Thank you guys,
Suebphatt*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you *can* put the files somewhere more permanent than /tmp, storing and accessing uploaded files outside the `public` directory is possible using the :url and :path parameters, along with a bit of configuration work.

An example extracted from code I wrote recently (it's modified enough that it might not work if you copy it verbatim):

```
app/models/picture.rb
  # Define the attachment
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => {:large  => ["700",      :jpg],
                                :thumb  => ["100x100>", :gif]},
                    :url => "/asset/picture/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":base/picture/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

config/initializers/storage.rb
  # Configure common attachment storage
  # This approach allows more flexibility in defining, and potentially moving,
  # a common storage root for multiple models.  If unneeded, just replace
  # :base in the :path parameter with the actual path
  Paperclip.interpolates :base do |attachment, style|
    /path/to/persistent/storage
    # A relative path from the Rails.root directory should work as well
  end

app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb
  # Make the attachment accessible
  def asset
    instance = Picture.find(params[:id])
    params[:style].gsub!(/\.\./, '')
    #check permissions before delivering asset?
    send_file instance.image.path(params[:style].intern),
              :type => instance.image_content_type,
              :disposition => 'inline'
  end

config/routes.rb
  # Add the necessary route
  match '/asset/picture/:id/:style/:basename.:extension', :to => 'pictures#asset'

app/views/pictures/show.html.erb
  <% # Display the picture %>
  <%= image_tag picture.image.url(:large) %>
```

Note this is all Rails 3 syntax.  A handful of changes would be needed to use it in Rails 2.x, but hopefully you get the, um, picture.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you can't - `/tmp` isn't configured as something that you can serve items out of (it's intended for temporary storage).

Can you access images at the `/tmp` URLs in your browser? Do they work?

Comment: Can you access images at the /tmp URLs in your browser? Do they work? ------ I can't. Anyway, thanks for advice :)

Comment: Actually, you can serve assets out of the tmp folder, albeit temporarily.  Here's an example of doing so:  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-compass  Unfortunately, I was unable to find an example of doing this specifically with images, although I would think a similar approach should work.  The best use-case would be for temporarily serving a dynamically created image.